# Is "still" being used correctly in "I love you still"?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order

I've heard this sentence in a song ('Build me up buttercup'):

> When you say you will, 
>   **but I love you still**

I'm used to seeing *still* in front of the verb or auxiliary verb as in "I still love you". Can *still* be used at the end of the sentence as in the song?

Comment: Incidentally (OK, *totally* off topic) the ska band Save Ferris has a wonderful cover of this, not that the original isn’t wonderful enough. Ever so slightly hard to find, but worth it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is appropriate usage.  As you noted, "still" is an adverb, so there's no confusion that it might be modifying "you" rather than "love".

It's basically used this way to create a grouping effect and add emphasis. In "I still love you," the assumed grouping is `still love` `you`.  In this version, the grouping is `love you` `still`, equivalent to `still` `love you`.  This emphasizes even more than it's his particular love for her that is ongoing, rather than his general capacity to love.

Comment: I think the second paragraph here has to be wrong. If I said *I still have a red stapler* surely you wouldn’t take that as placing emphasis on my general capacity to have things. The emphasis is on the stapler. I could even say: *I lost almost everything in the fire, but I still have my red stapler.*

Comment: I would say the emphasis is on the verb, "have." You *lost* everything, but you still *have* the red stapler. Also, the fire only started because you *didn't* have the stapler... :-(

Comment: @Jason I didn't meant to imply that the "regular" version places emphasis on the general capacity, just that the second version increases the emphasis on the object.  I do think there is a slight connotation placed by the regular version about the general capacity, though.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *I love you still* is standard, though you’re right that *still* most often appears before the verb.

It’s hard to say why the lyric is like this. Likely just for the rhyme or rhythm of it. The whole chorus just barely holds together, grammatically, poetically, or musically ...which is totally appropriate, given the situation, and a large part of the song’s charm.

If you want another theory, though, I’ve got one. ;)

Often people arrange sentences to put an element they want to emphasize last. See what I did there? It works! Adverbs that usually go before the verb are especially sweet candidates for that, since it is standard to put them at the end, but unusual enough to attract notice.

> *And behold, I am with you always, until the end of the age.* (Mt 28:20)

So I think what’s being emphasized here is the word *still*.

Answer (score 0):

> I love you, still. 
>   Is grammatically correct.

You're probably used to

> I still love you

Simply because it sounds better, and is correct as well.